# How to view relational data in both snippets in Django Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin, wagtail-snippet

I have defined two models "A" and "B" in Django Wagtail. Model "A" has a `ManyToManyField` relation with "B".  I use Wagtail `snippets` to edit them in the Admin panel. Is it possible to view both relational data items in each admin `snippets`? If so, I wanted to restrict the edit feature in model "A".

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `snippets`, I would encourage you to use Wagtail's `ModelAdmin` ([reference](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html?highlight=wagtail_hooks#installation)).  With `ModelAdmin`, you define a `wagtail_hooks.py` file in your app folder, and in that file you place the definitions of how you want the models to appear in the Wagtail admin (this construct is similar to how you would define things in Django's `admin.py`).  Then, in your `models.py` file, you will define `panels` for each model in a similar manner to how you define `panels` for your `Page`-based models, and the Wagtail admin will use these `panel` definitions when displaying a model instance for editing.  You can then customize the various views as needed, e.g., you can restrict the edit feature in model "A" as you stated ([reference](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/create_edit_delete_views.html)).